# how to iterate and access each values in django template?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, loops

I have a dictionary with following data:

```
   { "redirects": [
            {"status":"301","url":"/ca/products/marketing-cloud/"},
            {"status":"301","url":"https://www.example.com/ca/products/marketing-cloud/"},
            {"status":"301","url":"/ca/products/marketing-cloud/overview/"}
     ] 
   }
```

I tried with for loop as below

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
   {{ key }} => {{ value }
{% endfor %}
```

but it only prints

```
redirects => [{'status': '301', 'url': '/ca/products/marketing-cloud/'}, {'status': '301', 'url': 'https://www.example.com/ca/products/marketing-cloud/'}, {'status': '301', 'url': '/ca/products/marketing-cloud/overview/'}]
```

How can I iterate through it so I can access value of status,url ?

I am new to python and django. Please help to solve it.

Thank you.

Comment: use a for loop. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming your dictionary is named `data`:

```
{% for dict in data['redirects'] %}
    {% for k, v in dict.items %}
        {{ k }} => {{ v }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data is `data`.

```
for item in data['redirects']:
    status = item['status']
    url = item['url']
    print("Status: {}, URL: {}".format(status, url))
```

Let me know if you'd like some further explanation to this!

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please guide further on how to achieve in django template?